# Irrationlity of $e$

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers

Here is very simple "proof" of irrationality of $e$. I feel that I really miss something here, but can not find what.

Lets assume that there are finite integers $a$ and $b$
$$\frac{a}{b}=e=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i!}$$

Lets say there are integers $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$:
$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i!}$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{a}{b}$$
Now
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}>\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$$
and
$$a_{n+1}>\frac{a_{n}b_{n+1}}{b_{n}}$$
But $$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \ge n \implies a_{n+1}\ge a_{n}n$$
And as $a_n$ is integer, the $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$. So $a_n$ can not be a finite integer.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{a}{b}$ does not imply $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$. Also you would have to prove that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}>\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$ and $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \ge n$.

Comment: $a_{n+1}/b_{n+1} > a_n/b_n$ is immediate, but why would $b_{n+1}/b_n\geqslant n$ hold?

Comment: Thanks, the I agree with the details to be proved (which is simpe enough), but I would like to understand the mistake I made in a outline of proof.

Comment: @MartinR $\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} = \frac{a_n}{b_n} + \frac{1}{(n+1)!}.$

Comment: $$b_{n+1} = b_{n} n!$$ but you are right! Now I understand the mistake I made!

Comment: The last stretch looks weird. From $a_n\to\infty$ conclude $a_n$ can't be finite?! We fixed at the start $a_n$ is an integer for every $n$.

Comment: Should the final sentence be “So $a$ can not be a finite integer” ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main flaw in your argument is that $\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{a}{b}$ does not imply $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ (even if all fractions are in reduced form). A simple example is
$$
 \lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{1 + n}{1 + 2n} = \frac 12 \, .
$$

You also stated without proof that $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \ge n$ (which may be true or not).

Comment: Obvious, thank you:)

Comment: Improving of the "proof" based on this answer brings  as to regular proof:) There is a nice source here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyoH_vgiqXM